# spring controller : request mapping : 1 not and 1 should be there

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Have a method with not :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "!q")
```

and another with q

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "q")

Want another method without q but with t

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = "!q&t")
```

Will this work/ correct syntax? Other way?

Trying it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that doesn't work you can try

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"!q", "t"})
```